# Storing Method In Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am trying to write a program that can initialize classes from various submodules. In order to make it easy to expand the modules in future, I would like to store their constructor functions and some of the key functions in dictionaries. I am getting the issue with the functions not being recognized as an attribute and am not certain how to fix this. It seems to be fine for the constructors. The code should look something like this:

```
import my_class
class_ctor = {"my_class":my_class.my_class, ...}
class_func = {"my_class":my_class.my_class.func, ...}

my_inst = class_ctor["my_class"](what,ever,arguments)
my_inst.class_func["my_class"](some,other,arguments)
```

Inside my_class.py:

```
class my_class:
   def __init__(self):
      ...
   def func(...):
      ...
```

Is there a way that I could achieve something like this? I have seen a few examples which have dispatchers that work in a similar way, but would like to abstract this to methods.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: You do not need to do all this. If you want to extend the class, you may inherit the parent class as a child class

Comment: If I run the program, it says "my_class has no attribute called func".
And I am not trying to inherit the class. I have a main part of the program that acts like a sort of dispatcher to call functions from various different classes depending on which the user wants to run.

Comment: You have to share with us the content of `my_class.py` file. It will help us to assist you better

Comment: Okay, just added it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
my_inst.class_func["my_class"](some,other,arguments)
```

`class_func` doesn't belong to `my_inst` (from what you've shown).

Comment: Yeah, I think it would need to be `class_func['my_class'](my_inst, some, other, arguments)`

Comment: Oops, typo in the question. I meant to say that the method belongs to the class within the module. Fixed.
It may not be possible to do it. The other option is to have a function within the module that takes the instance of the class as a parameter and subsequently calls the function.

Comment: Yep! That did it. Didn't even think to pass the instance in for self, still just learning OOP in Python.